# Replace part of matrix by another matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A of size 1024x1024 and another matrix B of 512x512. How can I replace the central 512x512 portion of A by B?

Comment: You should tell us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to replace the elements from `(row_index, col_index) = (r, c)` (in your case probably `256,256`).

This should work:

```
A(r:(r+size(B,1)-1),c:(c+size(B,2)-1)) = B;
```

An example:

```
A = magic(6);
B = 2*ones(3);

r = 2;
c = 2;

A(r:(r+size(B,1)-1),c:(c+size(B,2)-1)) = B
A =

   35    1    6   26   19   24
    3    2    2    2   23   25
   31    2    2    2   27   20
    8    2    2    2   10   15
   30    5   34   12   14   16
    4   36   29   13   18   11
```

Comment: x and y are probably less useful for matrix coordinates than row and column (especially since the x is usually horizontal).